# Openmp program works without critical section

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

In an Openmp lecture a similar code is shown as a race condition in Openmp. In the for loop the sum+= is not in a critical section, so the order the threads are executed change the result.

But this is not the case in my program. No matter how often I run this program, the sum is always printed as 285 (1²+2²+3²+4²+5²+6²+7²+8²+9²). There doesn't seem to be any racecondition in my program at all.

```
 int main()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int a[10];
        int b[10];
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
            a[counter] = counter;
            b[counter] = counter;
        }


#pragma omp parallel for shared(sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sum += a[i] * b[i];  
    }
    cout << "sum is " << sum; // always prints 285
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The lecture specifically tells me that this program should not print the correct sum. To fix this they tell us to use either `#pragma omp critical` or `reduction(+:sum)`

Comment: Just because it does not exhibit wrong behaviour on *your* machine with *your* compiler and *your* compiler options does *not* mean there is no bug. A different compiler, different optimization option or different hardware may well expose the bug.

Comment: Jesper's comment is the correct answer. If you wanted to know the specific reason the race condition does not affect the result on your system. You must include your compiler version, compilation flags and specific system configuration in the question.

Comment: You compiler may look at the loop count and see that parallelization is unproductive.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, race conditions are about executing code in unpredictable order. But the order of addition doesn't matter, so you'll never get a race condition in this code

Comment: @ForceBru Race conditions is also about the fact that readers of a variable may see that variable in a partially changed state if no synchronization is used.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, right, but neither `a` nor `b` are changed... Or is it possible that different parts of the arrays are multiplied because of `i` being changed in a different thread?

Comment: @ForceBru `sum` might be particularly updated in one thread then a different thread writes to it, then the first thread completes is write, leading to a final incorrect value of `sum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because it does not exhibit wrong behaviour on *your* machine with *your* compiler and *your* compiler options does *not* mean there is no bug.

A different compiler, different optimization option or different hardware may well expose the bug.

Race conditions are tricky in that often they will not actually manifest as problems (except after months in production at your biggest customer late at night) in many cases or many configurations. 
Race conditions are still bugs and Undefined Behaviour (which means your compiler is allowed to assume they are not there and may actually use that assumption and subtly miscompile *other* parts of your program as a result).

Fact is that when multiple threads are modifying the same variable (or some are modifying and some are reading), you *need* to synchronise access to the shared variable - *always* - to be race free.